# Are Notifications triggered for linked questions and answers?

Tags: support, comments, linked-questions

***Scenario***

I found one of the answers from a SE user (let's say *ImaginaryUser*) very useful. The answer(let's say answer No."56789") was the third most upvoted answer but not accepted. A few days later, I come across a question (from let's say @NewbieUser) to which ImaginaryUser's answer is the perfect solution(the question is not a duplicate) So, I decide to link answer #56789 to the question by adding a comment.

> "Hey @NewbieUser, I know what exactly you are looking for. An answer is available at <[link](link to answer #56789)>."

Does my comment,once posted, automatically trigger a notification to ImaginaryUser, considering I have no option to notify him/her? Something like...

> "Your answer(*or question, whichever appropriate*) has been linked by BiscuitBoy in comment"

Similarly,do I get a notification, if another SE user links my question or answer in their post(question, answer or comment) in the same way described as above?

P.S: Winter Bash Hat Hunt is such a fun event! I wish it stays ON all year round (of course, with just respective change in season name)!!  Wishing all my fellow SE users a very merry Christmas.

Answer (score 3):

> Does my comment,once posted, automatically trigger a notification to ImaginaryUser, considering I have no option to notify him/her? Something like...

No the poster of that answer will not be notified. You cannot even  notify them explicitly (using a @ImaginaryUser) as long they weren't participating in the current post somehow.

---

You should also note that for marking duplicate-questions the question itself doesn't need to be an exact duplicate of the marked one.

It's more important, that the answers in the duplicate actually fit and solve the problem asked for.